# Converting image using matlab / octave from rgb to hsv back to rgb

Tags: matlab, octave, rgb, matlab-figure, hsv

I'm trying to convert a color image from rgb to hsv (make changes) then back to rgb.  As a test I made this code just to test how to go from rgb to hsv back to rgb but when I view the image it just shows up as black.  What am I missing?

*PS I'm using octave 3.8.1 which works like matlab

```
Here are the octave 3.8.1 packages I have loaded:
>>> pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
     control *|   2.6.2 | /usr/share/octave/packages/control-2.6.2
     general *|   1.3.4 | /usr/share/octave/packages/general-1.3.4
    geometry *|   1.7.0 | /usr/share/octave/packages/geometry-1.7.0
    parallel *|   2.2.0 | /usr/share/octave/packages/parallel-2.2.0
      signal *|   1.2.2 | /usr/share/octave/packages/signal-1.2.2
     specfun *|   1.1.0 | /usr/share/octave/packages/specfun-1.1.0
```

test code below:

```
f=imread('/tmp/bump.jpg'); %color image

%Hue - Saturation - Value 
f_rgb2hsv=rgb2hsv(f); %convert image to HSV double
f_hsv2rgb=hsv2rgb(f_rgb2hsv);%convert to RGB double
f_to_image=uint8(f_hsv2rgb); %convert to uint8 to see image
imshow(f_to_image);
```

[image: bump image]

Comment: Could you post some sample data, please....

Comment: @kkuilla I've attached the bump.jpg image to the question as the sample data you requested along with the test code above it.

Comment: How can you run `rgb2hsv` without the image package in Octave? I can't....

Comment: @kkuilla strange I did pkg list to show which packages are installed and added that to the question above ... It may have been manually added or included with another package...I''l have to research it to find out ... the octave sourceforge website is down at the moment but when it's back up I'll take a look

Comment: @kkuilla from what I've found out it looks like it was half installed on the main system, they said they will install the full image package.  Will this help me with my initial question?

Comment: I don't know but I think you are far better off by doing `f2= im2uint8(f_hsv2rgb);` as Daniel suggested. That gives me back the original image when I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double` images have values in range [0,1] (float), `uint8` images in range `[0,2^8-1]` (only integers). Using `uint8` you simply convert your values between 0 and 1 to 0 and 1 which is black or nearly black.

Use `im2uint8` or `im2double` to convert images, these functions automatically rescale your values to the appropriate range.

Comment: thanks but this requires the image toolbox / image package which I wont have access to.  Is there another way?

Comment: @RickT Why don't you do it yourself...? Just multiply by 255. Or try `imshow(f_to_image,[]);`.

Comment: @kkuilla I would but I'm not sure what to multiply.  I understand RGB is 0-255 but if the HSV is a decimal and I multiply by 1-255 I'm still left with a number and a decimal.  A simple example would help.

Comment: @kkuilla imshow(f_to_image,[]);  still shows a black image

Comment: @RickT: Standard answer for many missing functions. Get octave, copy the m file, fix the syntax (basically replace endfunction, endswitch etc with end), use it.